# Streaming Webcam Video to PHP5 Server

Tags: php

I have an urgent requirement as below

1. end user will be taking a online test
2. an admin will send instruction or command or request to this end user
3. upon this instruction webcam should be switched on , video should start recording
4. this video should now go to server from where admin can see who is taking the test.

There may be at a time 300 people taking the online test and 1 or few may be triggered for step 2 to 4.

online test part we are building in php/mysql.

we are not sure how to start this webcam and record video and send it back to server in a cost-effective manner.

If somebody can really throw some light , it will be a great deal.

Looking forward

Answer (score 0):

You problably need to design some plugin (e.g. with Flash technology) and integrate it within your html page. There is no standard way in html to communicate with external devices such as web camera. Php also doesn't relate to client hardware since it is server-side technology. I think, it's possible to find some Flash plugin examples in the internet which using web cam interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your pointers. when you say flash, can you give some pointers. I mean what does that mean and any known products we have to do this. Also, another parallel questoin on the same topic is , the user would have started the test. now, how do we communicate with him from server so that video can happen parallely